# If $T$ is self-adjoint, then $T+i I$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, with dense domain $D$. I am trying to show that $T+iI$ (where $I$ is the identity operator) is closed, in the sense that if $\{x_j\}$ is a sequence in $D$ such that $x_j \rightarrow x$ and $(T+iI)x_j \rightarrow y$, then $x\in D$ and $(T+iI)x = y$. I can show $\langle (T+iI) a,b\rangle = \langle = \langle a , (T-iI) b\rangle$, and I tried to use this relation, together with self-adjointness of $T$, to get the desired result. However, I was not successful. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $T$ is closed.

> $$x_i \to x, \quad (T+iI)x_i \to y \quad \Longrightarrow \quad Tx_i \to y-ix.$$